# how detect mouse click area in document - jquery - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a div element in it. i want when i clicked on outer area of that div element, then fade it out.

but i don't know how detect area of mouse click.
how detect that mouse click point is out of div area or not??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it). See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+click+outside+div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not very complicated - you have two options:
**1.** Asign onclick event to the outer area.

```
<div id="outer" onclick="$("#inner").fadeOut();">
    <div id="inner" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;/*disable bubling*/">Inner Div</div>
</div>
```

**2.** Traverse the dom and compare `event.target` (`event.srcElement`)

```
   document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
       var body = document.body;
       var target = event.target!=null?event.target:event.srcElement;
       var inner = document.getElementById("inner");
       while(target!=body) {
         if(target==inner)    //This means our inner element is clicked - or one of its children
           return false;
         target=target.parentNode;   //Go UP in the document tree
       }
       $("#inner").fadeOut();   //If we got here, none of element matched our inner DIV, so fade it out
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible jQuery solution:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var $div = $("#divId");
    if (!$div.is(e.target) && !$div.has(e.target).length) {
        $div.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5Jb5b/

Comment: Not IE compatible. I don't demand you to write function with all compatibility handling, but you should point out which things must be taken care of.

Comment: @TomášZato Eh? It's jQuery. It **is** compatible with IE. If you think that `e.target` in `on` method is derived in the same way as in `addEventListener`, you are wrong.

Comment: @Stano Updated in some sense :)

Answer (score 0):

function clickOn(e)
{

```
var target = e.target;
var optn = [];
optn.id = target.id; 
optn.optnClass = target.className.split(' ');
optn.optnType = target.optnName.toLowerCase();
optn.parent = target.parentNode; 
return optn;
```

}

document.body.onclick = function(e)
{

```
elem = clickOn(e);
var option_id = elem.id;
alert( 'option ID: '+option_id); // From id or other properties you can compare and find in which area mouse click occured
```

};